# Getting value of specific column for each row

Tags: excel, vba

I need to write script which allows me import data in xml format. It generates block of code I need for every order except variables. I need to go through all rows in range and get values from column "G". Problem is it gets only value of first row in range.

```
Dim rng As Range, row As Range
Set rng = Range(Range("G11"), Range("G11").End(xlDown))
For Each row In rng.Rows
Dim partner_id As String
partner_id = Cells(rng.row, 7).Value
line9 = "<typ:id>" & partner_id & "</typ:id>" & vbNewLine

...
```

I'm not a programmer as you can see, but I really need to get that partner_id. I would appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

You really should avoid using variable names which are the same as the common Methods used by Excel objects so, for instance, change `row` to be `myRow` perhaps.  That would then highlight what I think was causing your issue - the use of `rng.row` which, with a renamed variable, you would probably have written as `rng.myRow` - which would then give a compile error.

`rng.row` is simply returning the row number of the first cell in `rng`, and has nothing to do with your variable called `row`.

```
Dim rng As Range, myRow As Range
Set rng = Range(Range("G11"), Range("G11").End(xlDown))
'There's no need to use "rng.Rows" when each row is a single cell anyway
For Each myRow In rng
    Dim partner_id As String
    'because myRow is a single cell, we can just use its Value
    partner_id = myRow.Value
    line9 = "<typ:id>" & partner_id & "</typ:id>" & vbNewLine

    ...
```

---

FWIW - leaving your variable names and coding style unchanged, you could have fixed the code by using `row.Row` instead of `rng.Row`, i.e.

```
Dim rng As Range, row As Range
Set rng = Range(Range("G11"), Range("G11").End(xlDown))
For Each row In rng.Rows
Dim partner_id As String
partner_id = Cells(row.Row, 7).Value
line9 = "<typ:id>" & partner_id & "</typ:id>" & vbNewLine

...
```